# Is ∅ ∈ {{∅}} true?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I learned that the empty set is not an element of every set unless the empty set is explicitly included in the set like {∅}, so I believe it is false because it is not ∅ ∈ {∅}.

Comment: Of course, $\emptyset\in\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ is false.

Comment: This site is about [computer science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This question might be posted to [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: See the thread on [math.se]: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491465/is-emptyset-a-subset-of-emptyset/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is, in fact, false.

Remember, a set contains *only the things directly inside it*. A set of sets does not contain its elements' elements.

So the set $S = \{\{\varnothing\}\}$ has only one element: $\{\varnothing\}$. Since that one element is not $\varnothing$, $\varnothing$ is not in $S$.

Another way to think of it is to rename $\{\varnothing\}$ as $\xi$. Now you're wondering if $\varnothing \in \{\xi\}$. It should be clear now that the answer is "no".